# Save Dataset elements to files with specified file path

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I have a dataset of event case class that I would like to save the json string element inside it into a file on s3 with a path like bucketName/service/yyyy/mm/dd/hh/[SomeGuid].gz

So for example, the events case class looks like this:

```scala
case class Event(
  hourPath: String,  // e.g. bucketName/service/yyyy/mm/dd/hh/ 
  json: String  // The json line that represents this particular event.
  ... // Other properties used in earlier transformations.
)
```

Is there a way to save on the dataset where we write the events that belong to a particular hour into a file on s3?

Calling partitionBy on the DataframeWriter is the closest I can get, but the file path isn't exactly what I want.

Comment: What type of file do you want to save the data as? parquet?

Comment: In a Json format

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate each item and write it to a file in S3. It's efficient to do it with Spark because it will be executed in parallel.

This code is working for me:

```
val tempDS = eventsDS.rdd.collect.map(x => saveJSONtoS3(x.hourPath,x.json))

def saveJSONtoS3(path: String, jsonString: String) : Unit = {
    val bucketName = path.substring(0,path.indexOf('/'));
    val file = path.substring(bucketName.length()+1);

    val creds = new BasicAWSCredentials(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY)
    val amazonS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(creds)
    val meta = new ObjectMetadata();
    amazonS3Client.putObject(bucketName, file, new ByteArrayInputStream(jsonString.getBytes), meta)
 }
```

You need to import:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata
```

You need to include [aws-java-sdk](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk) library.